# Why can't I remove elements from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, splice

This function should remove elements that are less than 1 and more than 4, but it doesn't. The array is still the same.

```js
let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b) {
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (a > item && b < item) {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
        };
    });
};

filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4);
console.log(arr);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Tangential, but why not just use `Array.filter()` for this? Would be much, much cleaner than what you've got here.

Comment: Your issue is that no number can be less than 1 and greater than 4. You have your inequalities flipped (or should use or `||`)

Comment: Never modify the length of a collection you're iterating over unless you're aware of the consequences this can have.

Comment: @Andreas What consequences are you talking about? Why modifying the length is a bad thing?

Comment: @Ivan - if you are iterating over an array `[0,1,2,3]`, say you are filtering out elements equal to `1` or `2`.  When you are at index `1` and remove it, the array is now `[0,2,3]`.  But then you increment your index to `2`, which now points to the value `3`, and you never remove the value `2` because you never actually looked at it. `const arr = [0,1,2,3]; arr.forEach((el, i) => { if (el === 1 || el === 2) arr.splice(i, 1) }); console.log(arr);` will give you `[0,2,3]`

Comment: It seems likely Andreas is referring to potential side effects. In other words, where else is the array potentially used, what other code has access to it and might be expecting it to be a certain length, but now you've modified it, etc.

Comment: As dave already said. If you remove an element and you don't update the condition in your loop you will skip elements and/or run out of bounds of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When would an individual item be both less than 1 and more than 4?  If you want to remove items that are less than 1 *or* more than 4 you need to do:

```
if (a > item || b < item)
```

Comment: Interesting related read: http://llewellynfalco.blogspot.com/2016/02/dont-use-greater-than-sign-in.html. Definitely debatable, but this is one of the cases where it could help reading the conditional check IMHO: `item < a || b < item`.

Answer (score 0):

you are inverting the arguments when calling the function.
you should rather do

```js
filterRangeInPlace(arr, 4, 1)
```

Comment: Why? Does it make any difference?

Comment: you check if a is inferior and b superior so yes it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

you are basically keeping items between given range instead removing items go for keeping items this will return same
also use `filter` function it basically iterate through array and just like `foreach` there are two parameters inside it item and index the only difference is filter keeps value when you return true or ignore if you return false

you can check more about filter here [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

```js
let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1];

function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b) {
    return arr.filter(each=>{
       return each > a && each < b
    })
};

arr = filterRangeInPlace(arr, 1, 4);
console.log(arr);
```